# GMAT compilation does not generate gui

Tags: software, simulation, python, gmat

I am compiling GMAT 2020a on opensuse linux from source code downloaded from sourceforge.

I have gotten the compilation completed.  Ran ok, except the `/bin` directory only contains "console" gmat executables.  The console starts up an engine, so it says. There is no GUI (or GUI-beta) executable at all.  No messages seen during make that show any reason for GUI compilation to be skipped.

Any insights, anyone?

A second, minor issue is that Python file `configure.py` has error.  At line 301 it points to `/lib/libxerces-c.a` which should be `/lib64/libxerces-c.a`  Same with `libxerces-cd.a` following.

I don't mean to turn Space SE into a GMAT forum, but I don't find a GMAT forum anymore.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because better help could be found in software related community like Stack Overflow

Comment: @h22 **"better asked on" is not a close reason.** Can you demonstrate that this is clearly off-topic here? If not, we don't close just because with think it should be somewhere else. Have a look at the other questions associated with the tags the OP has added. This question fits here well enough; SO is not a room full of satellite orbital mechanics, but there are plenty of GMAT users here.

Comment: A highly technical software engineering question that can be best answered by some programmer really good in Python. Does not require expertise in space exploration.